I want to double click on one word from whole textarea. But whenever I tried to find element and double click it is selecting whole textarea
This is my textarea and I want click on any one word suppose I want to click on "Saturday" but this xpath gives whole text area not able to click on any one word. Please let me know how do I do this using Java selenium

I tried xpath and doubleClick metheod



//you need to use js, firstly focus the entire text, then search the word //you need then select it and click on it using js executar   

 WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.id("ai-script.....ETC"));

 
        String theWordYouNeedToClick = "Saturday";
        String script = "var textArea = arguments[0]; " +
                        "textArea.focus(); " +
                        "var start = textArea.value.indexOf('" + theWordYouNeedToClick + "'); " +
                        "var end = start + '" + theWordYouNeedToClick + "'.length; " +
                        "textArea.setSelectionRange(start, end); " 
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, textArea);



you need to use js, firstly focus the entire text, then search the word you need then select it and click on it using js executar
WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.id("ai-script.....ETC"));
    String theWordYouNeedToClick = "Saturday";
    String script = "var textArea = arguments[0]; " +
                    "textArea.focus(); " +
                    "var start = textArea.value.indexOf('" + theWordYouNeedToClick + "'); " +
                    "var end = start + '" + theWordYouNeedToClick + "'.length; " +
                    "textArea.setSelectionRange(start, end); " 
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, textArea);

